# LTRfootnote and savenotes of footnote package

Tags: footnotes

hey guys im trying to add LTRfootnote inside savenotes environment of footnote package, I tried \footnotemark \LTRfootnotetext approach but the numbering in footnote area was wrong. so i turned to savenotes environment, everything is fine when you use \footnote inside savenote enviroment but when i switch to LTRfootnote, footnote marks are there but footnote texts are missing. Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{CMU Serif}
\setlatinsansfont[Scale=1.1]{CMU Serif}
\setmathsfdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\begin{document}
\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption[text]{text}
\label{tab:3}
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm} }
    text&text\\
    \hline
    text\LTRfootnote{non-immunogenic}&text\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{savenotes}

some other text\LTRfootnote{some other FN}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please also include the part starting withe `\documentclass` till `\begin{document}` in your MWE

Comment: @albert done it. thanks. now its compilable.

Comment: Did you try to search the internet for 'LTRfootnote'?  Saw some sites like qa.parsilatex.com and www.parsilatex.com maybe they give some information (I don't know I cannot read the sites).

Comment: My guess is that both the `footnote` package and `bidi` mess with footnotes and are not aware of each other. `bidi` is so invasive that it usually has to be aware of other packages and explicitly support them. The footnote package is not listed among those which are supported (See §2 of the `bidi` manual)